# Unshaved/Unshaven

Tags: word-choice, difference

I'm trying to introduce a character in a script I'm writing...

> Sitting on the couch is Pete, late 20s, unshaved/unshaven, wearing a hoodie.

According to Google Books Ngram Viewer *unshaven* is a lot more common than *unshaved*, but what's the difference between them (I can't find any), and which one should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unshaven" is the usual form.

The verb "shave" can form either a regular past particple "shaved" or irregular "shaven" (the past tense form is now always regular).

But as an adjective, the form "shaven" and "unshaven" are preferred.

> His shaven head was a smooth bowl.

> John was unshaven, despite having an interview that afternoon.

But to form the present perfect and passive voice, "shaved" is at least as common.

> I have shaved and I'm ready to go.

> My beard was shaved by a barber.